# Simple Exchange Rate VLOOKUP Won't Work in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I made a simple table to convert from USD and EUR to CAD for my various subscriptions using VLOOKUP. USD works as expected but somehow EUR is returned with #N/A. Am I missing something?

I apologize for asking such a simple question but I just can't seem to figure out what went wrong.

[image: VLOOKUP Fail]

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your problem, not sure what the issue is but passing following parameter to `VLOOKUP` seemed to work for me:

```
=IF(E6="CAD", D6, D6*VLOOKUP(E6, Table1, 2, 0))
```

Last parameter specifies that you are looking for an exact match, not approximate. But not sure why that is the issue here.

Comment: also, just like in your case my recreation worked for USD but not for EUR.